# Setting up Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We are new to the Amazon WS business and technologies and would really appreciate some help and guidance. Just a higher level overview rather than a detailed explanation will do.

**Here is the problem**.

We run a dating site and want to move from our VPS to Amazon EC2(one instance) and RDS.
We also want to install a new dating script called aspnetdating which is originally designed for Windows Servers. 
The code is written in C# and uses ASP.NET 4.0.

**Here is ASPnetdating technical requirements**:

Microsoft Windows Vista/7 or Microsoft Windows Server 2000/2003/2008

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (not restricted by medium trust)

Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008/Express

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (only for source code customizations)

**Questions we would like to get help for**:

1) Do we need to adapt/modify/configure aspnetdating script in any way to install and run on Amazon EC2? RDS?
We understand that it's impossible for you to know how the dating software is programed to answer this question 
so just a help with a general direction (where to look and what to do) would be much appreciated.

2) Is there any cPanel or a similar tool to access all the services on Amazon WS? Our current VPS has cPanel which we use to acess File Server, phpMyAdmin, cron jobs and other services.

3) We would also need to configure the existing domain name into AWS.. How would we do this in AWS if domain name is with a 3rd party provider? Just a matter of pointing it to the new AWS location?

4) Can we run SQL server and Windows Server inside EC2 - or should the SQL side always go into an RDS instance. Pros & cons of each option?

5) Based on ASPnedtading technical requirements from above we would like to make the best choice out of a large number of options available on Amazon EC2 Set Up Wizard. We kind of lost. Please help us.

Kind regards,
Igor

Answer (score 1):

1. Its possible. IF you use RDS you get a managed instance of the database server you select. Some features may not be available.
2. No, but you can install one if you like. However, being that the entire infrastucture is NAT'd you might have some issues with licencing since some control panels run on having a public IP assigned directly to the machine.
3. You can keep your domain/dns where its at. Route53 does provide some advantages with aliases, if you are using load balancers.
4. You can do either. RDS is automated and managed, but often some features are not available or disabled. In addtion you generally pay for licencing by the hour for SQL server. If you set it up yourself and have a licence you can run it without additional cost. With your own instance you have access to all the features SQL server provides.
5. The setup wizard just helps you launch an instance. All that will ultimately matter is which version of windows and which size instance you want to run.